# Should questions that answer themselves answer themselves in the answer section of the post

Tags: discussion, questions

For example, if I discover that a compiler has an error, would posting the question and answer to that question in the question section of the post be considered a bad thing to do in this site? Should I post the question and answer separately instead?

Comment: Yes, we encourage self-answering, see the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: see also: [Post part of the answer in your own question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354298/839601)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> would posting the question and answer to that question in the question section of the post be considered a bad thing to do in this site?

Yes.  The question is where you ask a question, not where you post an answer.

> Should I post the question and answer separately instead?

Yes, just be sure that both the question and the answer are of high quality when evaluated independantly.  It's not okay to ask a bad question just because you're answering it, and a bad answer isn't automatically good just because it's the question author that answered it.